# How to do countdown timer for refilling?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

I am currently working on Adobe AIR app game that requires passes for each level. I would like to do the function when the passes has reaches 0, the player needs to wait for 2hrs for their passes to be refilled. Once the countdown timer ends, the passes will be refilled to 3.

How would it be possible for AS3 to do it and keep the timer running even the app is closed?

Comment: Use server side, otherwise they would just change local time and voila.

Comment: How will I do it? I'm really a beginner in AS3 and it's my first time to work on an online application. My application is for my Thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way imo would be to store timer start date/time in [SharedObjects](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html) and now even if you kill the app, you can get stored date/time and calculate how much time passed since then. If more than 2h you just refill passes. If less, you set the timer for the amount of time you have left.

But like @Vesper said, this approach is vulnerable and you can "cheat" by changing local time. If you need your app to prevent such a thing you should never trust the client and you should use server side.
Flow can be something like:

- On app start, sent Handshake request to the server (by using [URLRequest](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) for example)
- Server respond with current time and you calculate time lapsed based on that value.

Comment: Thank you @3vilguy. I will study the reference you had gave. :)

Comment: No worries :) Let me know how it went and good luck with your Thesis.